# android: Связь между broadcast receiver и fragment

Tags: android

Передаю с сервиса в onHandleIntent() кастомный объект через LocalBroadcastManager.

```
Intent i = new Intent(ACTION);
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CARD_OBJECT, cardObject);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(i);
```

Во фрагменте ресивер ловит интент, но почему-то он там null.

```
private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        CardObject cardObject = intent.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_CARD_OBJECT); // cardObject - null
        mAdapter.addCard(cardObject);
    }
};

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
}

 @Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```

Код кастомного класса:

```
public class CardObject implements Parcelable {
private String mCelsius;
private String mCFahrenheit;
private String mSuggestion;
private String mCityName;
private String mBreezoMeterAqi;
private Bitmap mCityPicture;
private String mBreezoColor;

public CardObject() {

}

public void setBreezoColor(String mBreezoColor) {
    this.mBreezoColor = mBreezoColor;
}

public void setCelsius(String mCelsius) {
    this.mCelsius = mCelsius;
}

public void setCFahrenheit(String mCFahrenheit) {
    this.mCFahrenheit = mCFahrenheit;
}

public void setSuggestion(String mSuggestion) {
    this.mSuggestion = mSuggestion;
}

public void setCityName(String mCityName) {
    this.mCityName = mCityName;
}

public void setBreezoMeterAqi(String mBreezoMeterAqi) {
    this.mBreezoMeterAqi = mBreezoMeterAqi;
}

public void setCityPicture(Bitmap mCityPicture) {
    this.mCityPicture = mCityPicture;
}

public String getBreezoColor() {
    return mBreezoColor;
}

public String getCFahrenheit() {
    return mCFahrenheit;
}

public String getSuggestion() {
    return mSuggestion;
}

public String getCityName() {
    return mCityName;
}

public String getBreezoMeterAqi() {
    return mBreezoMeterAqi;
}

public Bitmap getCityPicture() {
    return mCityPicture;
}

public String getCelsius(){
    return  mCelsius;
}


private CardObject(Parcel in) {
    mCelsius = in.readString();
    mCFahrenheit = in.readString();
    mSuggestion = in.readString();
    mCityName = in.readString();
    mBreezoMeterAqi = in.readString();
    mCityPicture = in.readParcelable(Bitmap.class.getClassLoader());
}

public static final Creator<CardObject> CREATOR = new Creator<CardObject>() {
    @Override
    public CardObject createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new CardObject(in);
    }

    @Override
    public CardObject[] newArray(int size) {
        return new CardObject[size];
    }
};


@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(mCelsius);
    dest.writeString(mCFahrenheit);
    dest.writeString(mSuggestion);
    dest.writeString(mCityName);
    dest.writeString(mBreezoMeterAqi);
    dest.writeParcelable(mCityPicture, flags);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы объявили интент с именем i, а данные кладёте в какой-то другой

```
Intent i = new Intent(ACTION);
i.putExtra(EXTRA_CARD_OBJECT, cardObject); // В этой строке кладёте в intent, а надо в i
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(i);
```

Comment: Невнимательность:) Спасибо!

Comment: Всегда рад помочь :)